# Логика приложения

Tags: java, mysql, алгоритм, логика

Имеются сущности: Преподаватели, студенты, курсы.

Преподаватели могут: создавать курсы, смотреть кто из студентов на курсы записан, подтверждать что студент курс прошел.

Студенты могут: записываться на различные курсы, смотреть на какие курсы уже записан, смотреть какие курсы уже прошел.

Курсы:  имеют поле преподавателя, создавшего курс

Каким образом для этого реализовать курсы?
Создавать массив студентов для каждого курса? мне кажется будет проблема с доступом конкретного студента к информации о курсах на которые записан.

Для каждого студента создавать новый обьект курс, и к нему добавлять имя студента?

Как запретить студенту несколько раз покупать один и тот же курс?

Comment: Как вы хотите это реализовывать - с помощью СУБД, на каком-то конкретном языке программирования или как?

Comment: java & mysql, добавил в теги

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи напрашивается использование реляционной бд, к примеру MySQL. Подходящей схемой может оказаться следующая:

таблица `students`

таблица `courses`, у каждого курса есть связь с `teachers`

таблица `teachers`

таблица `course_students`, реализующая связь "многие ко многим"

**UPD:** Опишу подробнее.

Таблицы `students`, `teachers`, `cources` должны иметь поле `id (int, primary key)`, остальное по необходимости. Таблица courses дополнительно имеет поле `teacher_id (int, foreign key в таблицу teachers по желанию`).

Для реализации n*m связи в таблице `course_students` требуются всего два поля: `course_id`, `student_id`, оба типа `int`.

Сама информация по конкретным курсам и студентам хранится в таблицах `courses` и `students`.

Comment: а что именно заносить в course_students. Новые курсы с привязкой к конкретным студентам? ил тольок имена студентов?